# Safely / securely send configuration information to front-end

Tags: angularjs, security, web, frontend, web-frontend

I am a bit curious about the best way to send configuration information to the front-end - we have a web server serving up pages and an API server serving the JSON API - currently the urls for the API server are just in an Angular service, basically hardcoded in a front-end JS file. Something slightly more "secure" would be to send the configuration as some sort of object with each request. But I get the feeling that most people would say this is just obfuscation and not really secure at all. What is the best way to do this? Maybe there's just no way to prevent someone from redirecting requests to some other server besides ours?

One way to sort of solve this would be to direct all traffic back to the web server which in turn makes requests to the API, but I am not sure if that's a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with implementing HTTPS if you wanted security.  Beyond this if you have no authentication or authorization to connect users with requests then that would probably be a good place to continue after HTTPS.

HTTPS handles the issue you mentioned concerning redirects (though users can still ignore the big warning their browser should give them).  In general, when properly implemented it should prevent most common MITM attacks.  For the authentication, the requests will need to be in some way connected to the user (session_id) which the API server can check to authenticate.  For authorization, the API server should be able to determine if an authenticated user is authorized to make any given request.

It really is dependent on what your requirements are.  Is the information accessed via the API public?  Should all users be able to access?  Is the only concern interception/modification of the response (Man-In-The-Middle MITM)?